# In iOS9 Dropbox App is not being opened. Instead webview is being opened for login

Tags: ios, objective-c, dropbox-api, ios9

So, I am using Dropbox Core API SDK in my project and it used to work smoothly (i.e. opening Dropbox app, if installed on device, for logging in; Or opening UIWebView when dropbox app was not installed on device) right until iOS9.

In iOS9 (public beta) UIWebView is getting opened irrespective of whether the Dropbox app is installed or not!!

I searched about this issue, or a patch release in dropbox forum, but couldn't find any.

NOTE: I am suspecting it has something to do with the new privacy & securities settings added in iOS9, but there hasn't been any text regarding this in dropbox forum.

Comment: Did you know this: http://awkwardhare.com/post/121196006730/quick-take-on-ios-9-url-scheme-changes

Comment: Yes, this is new in iOS 9. Apple now requires that your app pre-register any URL schemes that you plan to open in the app.

http://www.macstories.net/linked/ios-9-bringing-changes-to-url-schemes/

Try adding dbapi-2?

Comment: @LeahCulver Adding dbapi-2 solved the problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

This may become an issue when Dropbox update their app for iOS9. They will also have to declare the LSApplicationQueriesSchemes entry for your app. Will they add all schemes for all apps that support dropbox?
If not, then you declaring "dbapi-2" will end up as a one-way trip for the user to the Dropbox app, but not back.

Comment: It looks like the latest update has removed the restriction for openURL: and it just applies to canOpenURL: